# How to get response from jsp which calls out api?

Tags: javascript, jsp, rest

We have login.html screen with form and button which submittes that form. Form calls jsp file which calls one api for authentication of citizens. When user login to that api, api returns data about user in xml. Then it should be redirected to starting html but with new data returned from that api. Now we configured it to redirect to our rest service which returns data as json. But how to access this data? It only opens our rest service url and we see json in response.

Answer (score 0):

The REST service should return with a response containing different URLs. One for viewable representation (an HTML may be), one for printing, one for JSON and so on. Client may choose whichever is applicable.

In your login workflow, it looks like that you should use some sort of callback URL also. Implement callback in JSP. While submitting to API service the JSP will include a callback URL as parameter. After the service completes its work the client should be redirected by the API towards the callback URL. The callback URL receives the parameters supplied by service and sends a response to the client after processing.

```
-> Client
-> login.html
-> (redirect client to API, params include JSP callback)
-> API processes the request
-> (redirect client to JSP callback with its own response as params)
-> JSP will process the response
-> redirect client to login.html
-> login.html decides next page.
```